# SQL SERVER - prioritize cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem: I have a table with MainID, JobID and EmployeeID (badly chosen names, but that's not changable right now).

```
MainID | EmployeeID | JobID
100    | 100        | 100
100    | 100        | 101
NULL   | 100        | 102
```

Now, I want to add an extra column which shows what record has the main contract(1) and which records has not(2)

The cases are:

- IF MainID == JobID -> Main contract
- IF MainID <> JobID AND MainID IS NULL -> Not main contract
- IF MainID IS NULL -> Main contract, ONLY if the main contract is still not found after the first 2 cases.

The SQL Statement I tried was:

```
SELECT MainID , EmployeeID, JobID,
CASE
WHEN JobID = MainID  THEN 1
WHEN JobID != MainID  THEN 2
WHEN MainID  IS NULL AND not exists(SELECT JobID,MainID 
            FROM TableA
            WHERE JobID = MainID 
            ) THEN 1
ELSE 2

END AS MainContract
FROM     TableA
ORDER BY SnapshotDate, EmployeeID
```

This works well for the first 2 cases, but it sets all records on 2 (meaning not main contract) if the MainID is null.

Any suggestions or other ideas?

Comment: I mean, the second case is just `MainID IS NULL`, right?

Comment: Correct. It was just documented that way :)

Comment: `CASE` evaluates in the same order as is written, so you may want to put more specific condition `is null and not exists` before the less specific.

Comment: I don't get it. (MainID IS NULL) -> Main contract. But in sql (MainID IS NULL) ->(MainID <> JobID for any JobID) ->Not main contract. ??

Answer (score 0):

A quick shuffle:

```
select
case
    when JobID = MainID then 1
    when not exists
        (
        select 1
        from TableA T1
        where T1.JobID=T1.MainID
        and T1.JobID = T2.JobID
        ) then 1
    else 2
end as MainContact
from TableA T2
```